# how to remove only the first two leading spaces in all lines of a files

Tags: linux, awk, sed, space

my input file is like

```
  *CONTROL_ADAPTIVE
  $  adpfreq    adptol    adpopt    maxlvl    tbirth    tdeath     lcadp    ioflag
        0.10     5.000         2         3       0.0       0.0         0         0
```

I JUST want to remove the leading 2 spaces in all the lines.

I used

```
sed "s/^[ \t]*//" -i inputfile.txt
```

but it deletes all the space from all the lines.. I just want to shift the complete text in files to two position to left.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: `sed "s/^[ \t][ \t]//" -i inputfile.txt`

Comment: `sed -i 's/  //' inputfile.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You can specify that you want to delete two matches of the character set in the brackets:

```
sed -r -i "s/^[ \t]{2}//" inputfile.txt
```

See the output:

```
$ sed -r "s/^[ \t]{2}//" file
*CONTROL_ADAPTIVE
$  adpfreq    adptol    adpopt    maxlvl    tbirth    tdeath     lcadp    ioflag
      0.10     5.000         2         3       0.0       0.0         0         0
```

Comment: of the character set in the brackets not of the character.

Comment: you can also use `[[:blank:]]` for the "space" or `[[:space:]]`

Comment: Yes, @NeronLeVelu , there are many options. Also in comments a couple of good ones were suggested. Thanks!